# Is it safe to use the standard /tmp folder with upload_tmp_dir in PHP?

Tags: php, post, tmp

I was wondering if there is any security risk when using the default upload_tmp_dir value in the php.ini file? If yes, what are better approaches or places to place these files?

Comment: If you are on shared hosting or you have more projects running on the same machine it means other projects / users might also be able to access things stored in `/tmp`

Comment: But when using your own server or using some sort of VPS there is no reason for using an other folder at an different location or something like that?

Answer (score -1):

/tmp means temporary. So this folder may normally be cleared regularly. You should create a /upload folder and put your files inside it.

EDIT : 
Excuse me I didn't anwer properly. I think there is no security risk if the folder is not accessible from the internet. For example outside the www folder.

Comment: I understand that the /tmp folder is temporary. I mean what else could tmp stand for ;) , but by clearing the folder does not protect or restrict any files in the /tmp folder at any given time. And as you can read in my question I am interested in the risks involved when using the standard /tmp folder

Comment: Ok, so if Apache is installed and the script accepts some kind of data like an image then that image will be stored in the /tmp folder. So there is no direct communication with the sever but when uploading an file there will be an file stored inside the /tmp folder.